# Categorize posts by months and years in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am a noob in Django, and I am doing a project with lots of trials and errors. Here's a case. I want to implement this on my site:

[arc asia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz0nw.png)

Each entry will have posts grouped by the months and the years. If I click, I will get to see bunch of posts on that month and year.

My site only has 4 posts now, all of which were on last September. The look that I managed to do is the following, which obviously is wrong because Sep 2022 should be a single entry. There has to be some way to do the group by but I can't seem to achieve that:

[group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqobC.png)

I wanted to do it with an archive view, as I failed at that attempt, I am doing in this way. I'd like to know both ways. Here are the relevant files:

```
blog/models.py

class News(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    news_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique_for_date='nw_publish')
    news_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='news_posts')
    news_body = RichTextField()
    image_header = models.ImageField(upload_to='featured_image/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)  # this

    nw_publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    nw_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%name' % {'name': self.news_title}

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('nw_publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.news_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:news_detail', args=[self.slug])
```

```
blog/views.py

class NewsListView(TagMixin, ListView):
    model = News
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'newss'
    template_name = 'blog/news.html'


class NewsDetailView(TagMixin, DetailView):
    model = News
    date_field = "nw_publish"
    context_object_name = 'news'
    template_name = 'blog/news_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['news_details_view'] = News.objects.all()
        data['news_years'] = News.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('nw_publish')).values('year').annotate(total_entries=Count('year'))
        return data


class NewsTagView(TagMixin, ListView):
    model = News
    context_object_name = 'newss'
    template_name = 'blog/news.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return News.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('tag_slug'))


class NewsYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    context_object_name = 'news_years'
    date_field = "nw_publish"
    year_format = '%Y'
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True
    queryset = News.objects.filter(nw_status='published').order_by('nw_publish', 'news_title')
```

```
blog/urls.py

from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views
from .views import Home, HomeDetail, Contact, ReportListView, ReportDetailView, NewsListView, NewsDetailView, \
    MemberListView, ProjectListView, ProjectDetailView, SearchView, ReportYearArchiveView, PhotoGallery, AboutDetail, \
    VideoGallery, FCListView, ReportTagView, NewsTagView, NewsYearArchiveView
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

# , Gallery

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    # post views

    path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path("search", SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('home/<slug:slug>/', HomeDetail.as_view(), name='details'),
    path('news/', NewsListView.as_view(), name='news_list'),
    path('news/<slug:slug>/', NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail'),
    path('news/taggit/tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', NewsTagView.as_view(), name='post_tag'),
    path('news/<int:year>/', NewsYearArchiveView.as_view(), name="news_year_archive"),
    
]
```

```
templates/news_details.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% block container %}
    <div class="stricky-header stricked-menu main-menu">
        <div class="sticky-header__content"></div><!-- /.sticky-header__content -->
    </div><!-- /.stricky-header -->
    <!--News Details Start-->
    ...
   
                        <div class="sidebar__single sidebar__category">
                            <h3 class="sidebar__title">Archives</h3>

                            <ul class="sidebar__category-list list-unstyled">
                                 {% for y in news_years %}
                                <li><a href={{ y.get_absolute_url }}><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>{{ y }}</a></li>
                               {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar__single sidebar__tags">
                            <h3 class="sidebar__title">Popular Tags</h3>

                            <div class="sidebar__tags-list">
                                {% for tag in tags %}
                                <a href="{% url 'blog:post_tag'  tag.slug %} ">{{ tag.name }}</a>
                               {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--News Details End-->
{% endblock %}
```

What I am trying to do:

1. Combine all the same months and years posts together
2. Making the list clickable
3. Showing a list of the posts after the click (how to get this list?)

Sorry I am a newbie and I don't know Django that muuch; still learning hence I am stuck with this problem.

What I am trying to do:

Combine all the same months and years posts together
Making the list clickable
Showing a list of the posts after the click (how to get this list?)
Sorry I am a newbie and I don't know Django that muuch; still learning hence I am stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing missing is a [**`.order_by()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) (yes, I know that is strange), this will force a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
data['news_years'] = (
    News.objects.annotate(year=ExtractYear('nw_publish'))
    .values('year')
    .annotate(total_entries=Count('year'))
    .order_by()
)
```

as for using months, it might be better to *truncate* than extract, since then you still have a date object:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

data['news_years'] = (
    News.objects.values(month=TruncMonth('nw_publish'))
    .annotate(total_entries=Count('month'))
    .order_by()
)
```

> Showing a list of the posts after the click (how to get this list?)

You can make a path with the year and month with:

```
path(
    'posts/<int:year>/<int:month>/', SomeListView.as_view(), name='posts-by-month'
),
```

then in the template you link to this with:

```
{% for news_year in news_years %}
    <a href="{% url 'posts-by-month' news_year.month.year news_year.month.year %}">{{ news_year.month }} ({{ news_year.total_entries }})</a>
{% endfor %}
```

in the `SomeListView`, you can then filter with:

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
    model = News

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(
                nw_publish__year=self.kwargs['year'],
                nw_publish__month=self.kwargs['month'],
            )
        )
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I have been ill. 
I'm facing an error with your month truncate operation, 'field' not found error. Also facing issue in template. Am I missing something? 
Also, thank you so much, and I had no idea that it is order_by in Django :/

Comment: @SanjiVinsmoke: what field is not found?

Comment: from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

data['news_years'] = (
    News.objects.values(month=TruncMonth('nw_publish'))
    .annotate(total_entries=Count('year'))
    .order_by()
)
If I write this, I am getting FieldError for 'year' .

Comment: @SanjiVinsmoke: ah yes, forgot to change the field from `year` to `month`.

Comment: In the template, I'm getting "Reverse for 'posts-by-month' not found. 'posts-by-month' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: @SanjiVinsmoke: did you give the `path(..)` the name `name='posts-by-month'`?

Comment: Yes. here's what I wrote, NewsMonths is the name of my view class

path('news/<int:year>/<int:month>/', NewsMonths.as_view(), name='posts-by-month')

Comment: @SanjiVinsmoke: did you define an `app_label=...` in that `urls.py`? Then you prefix the name of the url with `{% url 'app_label:posts-by-month' ... %}`

Comment: Yap, that was it. I need to show all the posts that fall under this particular year and month. I made a template, but I don't know how to map the URL with those posts (like ../2022/09 will show all the posts on September 2022. My individual post has slug and some tags; here are the URLs: 
path('news/', NewsListView.as_view(), name='news_list'),
    path('news/<slug:slug>/', NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail'),
    path('news/taggit/tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', NewsTagView.as_view(), name='post_tag'),
    path('news/<int:year>/<int:month>/', NewsMonths.as_view(), name='posts-by-month'),